# Grails app upgrade 2.5 - dataSource is null

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am upgrading my Grails application from version 2.0 to 2.5.4 and facing NullPointerException as the dataSource is null. This code worked fine in Grails version 1.3, 2.0 but not in version 2.5.
Below is the code:

resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
...
jdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate) {
   dataSource = ref('dataSource')
...
}
```

DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    configClass = GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.class
    pooled = true
    autoreconnect= true 
}

hibernate {
    generate_statistics=true
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' 

}


environments {
   development {
      dataSource {
         driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         username = "test"
         password = "test"
         dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
         pooled = true
         jmxExport = true
         url = "jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName?autoReconnect=true"
    }
}


}
```

Service class

```
def jdbcTemplate

def someMethod(){
    jdbcTemplate.queryForList(somequery) 
}
```

Exception:
Cannot invoke method queryForList() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method queryForList() on null object

Edited: Few Observations:
1. Db opetaions like DomainClass.list() are working fine, data is fetched from DB
2. def jdbcTemple - Instance of jdbTemplate is created in BootStrap.groovy class, but it is null in service and controller classes

Answer (score 0):

Your dataSource is encapsulated in a environment block.

```
grails run-app //this runs in development environment mode

grails run-war //this runs in production environment mode
```

Please check what environment is in use during run-time (See logs).

Comment: Yes, I am running grails run-app and this runs in development environment, also tried putting same dev db details in all environments, but same error.

Comment: @nshweta Feels like a bug then, raise your issue on https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues with a reproducible case.

If you would like to see what's going on, set the log level to debug/info and see if spring threw any error in creating bean.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue, one of the methods in service which was being called from controller was marked as private (this is an old code written before couple of years, it was working fine with earlier versions of Grails/Groovy). With Grails version 2.5 and Groovy 2.4, this is not allowed. However, the error it was giving was not method not found, but it was saying the datasource that was in the method was null.